# Execute XHR javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

I'm making a single page app, and in this application; I'd like to download some arbitrary javascript code and execute it on the current page. It would not make sense in my situation to download "all" of the scripts that could execute on this page at once.

So is there a safe way to execute javascript that has been downloaded from a server via an XHR request. I was going to do the obvious and execute the downloaded string as javascript using eval, but I'd imagine this could be a security issue, and I constantly read of the evils of eval.

Can anybody comment on whether this would be safe?
Is there an alternative method to XHR downloading scripts as strings and then calling them?

Comment: Eval is as unsafe as any other methods of running a script, the best you could do to protect the user is sandbox the script in some way.

Comment: It's only dangerous if a third party could manipulate the string you want to eval. Though eval is not really need, you just as well simply attach a new script-element to the body with a src-attribute pointing to your js-file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that note please? Since the scripts will be coming from my server (and I've written them), I'm not worried that the scripts themselves will contain malicious code, I'm only worried that somehow, a malicious user could inject malicious code.

Comment: Why would you need to use eval? Javascript is not subject to cross domain restrictions just append the script tag to the dom in the normal way

Comment: If the browser-server communication is itself endangered, you can't really defend yourself software-wise. An attacker could inject arbitrary code in every request. That's not a problem you fix *inside* your code. For everything else, have trust in the protocols and validate **all** requests server-side.